# Comparing two JSON files from different sources (same schema) in Boomi

Tags: json, boomi

How can I compare JSON files from two different sources (same schema)in Boomi. If there is a difference, we reject the payload with error stating fields cannot be changed. Note that there may be upwards of 200 attributes.

Comment: I don't really know what Boomi is, but if you're just trying to detect whether there's a difference in the files-- a binary yes or no answer-- then a checksum seems like a good place to start.

Comment: The question is specific to Boomi implementation. With 200+ attributes and a large number of rules, not sure if Boomi shape compare is the right approach. If someone has other options, much appreciated.

Comment: Probably best to use a library with such a function, like the Lodash javascript library with it's isEqual () method. (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual)